# Python: Difference between add and __add__

Tags: python

In Python, what is the difference between `add` and `__add__` methods?

Comment: As of writing this question I couldn't find a duplicate.

Comment: to which "add" method are you referring?

Comment: Was the http://docs.python.org site down?  What stopped you from searching the official documentation?  What was confusing about the official documentation?

Comment: Googling didn't help me hence I posted here. And there are far more sillier questions out there on SO. You're an expert doesn't mean everyone's an expert. At times keywords on Google don't yeild desired results and it's then that I come to SO coz I know people like you exist who flame people like me who have (silly) doubts.

Comment: -1 because I googled for `__add__` and i got useful python information in the first matches

Comment: @joaquim There is no motvie to downvote questions just because there exists information about thequestion in other places. You are free not to answer, or to point to other resources - the question is no less valid.

Comment: "If it's a dupe of other information available elsewhere on the Internet, don't assume that that information will always be available elsewhere on the Internet forever or that it's in a reasonable, peer-reviewed, editable form... we have always encouraged copying information into Stack Overflow even if it exists elsewhere." -- Joel Spolsky http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134645/is-stack-overflow-a-central-store-for-tutorials

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A method called `add` is just that - a method with that name. It has no special meaning whatsoever to the language or the interpreter. The only other thing that could be said about it is that sets have a method with the same name. That's it, nothing special about it.

The method `__add__` is called internally by the `+` operator, so it gets special attention in the language spec and by the interpreter and you override it to define addition for object of a class. You don't call it directly (you can - they're still normal methods, they only get called implicitly in some circumstances and have some extra restrictions - but there's rarely if ever a reason - let alone a *good* reason). See the [docs on "special" methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) for details and a complete list of other "special" methods.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you just went through this doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html and was curious about the differences between e.g.

```
operator.add(a, b)
operator.__add__(a, b)
```

Check the source code https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/operator.py :

```
def add(a, b):
    "Same as a + b."
    return a + b

...
# All of these "__func__ = func" assignments have to happen after importing
# from _operator to make sure they're set to the right function
...
__add__ = add
```

So

```
print(3 + 3)              # call 'operator.__add__' which is `operator.add`
import operator
print(operator.add(3, 3)) # call 'operator.add' directly
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the earlier posts, `__*__` are often discouraged as names for identifiers in own-classes unless one is doing some hacking on core-python functionality, like modifying / over-loading standard operators, etc. And also, often such names are linked with **magical** behavior, so it might be wise to avoid using them in own-namespaces unless the **magical** nature of a method is implied.

See [this post](http://codesinger.blogspot.com/2009/02/dont-use-in-python-unless-you-are.html) for an elaborate argument

Comment: Actually it is not that "misterius"  creating your own `__*__` methods in your classes is rather straightforward - no need to make it sound that esoteric.